# Saving image from viewpager into a custom gridview gallery

Tags: android, image, gridview, android-viewpager

Im building an application in Android Studio. My MainActivity is fairly simple, existing out of;

Imageview(Logo)

Viewpager(Swipeable images (10x)

ImageButton(Dislike image)

ImageButton(Like image)

Button (My personal cookbook) This button sends the user to their personal cookbook where all the images are "Liked".

The thing that I'm trying to achieve is to be able to press the ImageButton(Like) and save the image that is being **showed** from the ViewPager in "My personal Cookbook".

The next thing that I also want to achieve is, that when the **Dislike** is pressed that the Imageviewer deletes the image and goes on to the next image in the PageViewer.

I've tried searching everywhere on how to get this going but I can't find it.
Therefor I hope that someone here will be able to help me with these 2 questions.

With kind regards,

A.

```
    // Locate the ViewPager in viewpager_main.xml
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    // Pass results to ViewPagerAdapter Class
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this, mealname, mealpicture);
    // Binds the Adapter to the ViewPager
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, CookbookActivity.class));
        }
    });

    // Check Authentication
    mRef = new Firebase(com.example.sick.foodinspiration.Constants.FIREBASE_URL);
    if (mRef.getAuth() == null) {
        loadLoginView();
    }
}

// Dont pay attention to this
//public void DislikeMethod(View view){
   //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Dislike :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

// Dont pay attention to this
 //public void LikeMethod (View view){
    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Like :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}

private void loadLoginView() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: where is your button like ?

Comment: Currently not added in the MainActivity. But they will be placed in the DislikeMethod and LikeMethod. The ImageButtons layout is placed in the activity_main

Answer (score 0):

```
Button likebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.likebtn);
    Button dislikebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dislikebtn);

    likebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //LikeMethod();
        }
    });

    dislikebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()+1);//move to next image
            //DisLikeMethod();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Alright I've added viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()+1);
To the Dislike ImageButton and to the Like ImageButton. I am able to go trough the viewpager with this. So this means my 2nd questions is fixed.
Thnx allot for helping me achieve this!

The next step is saving the current item in the GridView (CookbookActivity) when the LikeButton is pressed.
Should I make a database for this?
I'm currently working with Firebase. So the user has to fill in his/her email and password. (This works fine)

Comment: thats good your one problem is solve accept my answer so that it help other you should need database if required otherwise you can also used sharedpref for that

Answer (score 0):

Use sqlite database for achieve this

First create a table called MyCookBook and create the columns such as ID(integer),ImagePath/Url(text),isLike(int 0,1)

Once user click the like button insert the image path and set isLike column as 1
If user click dislike button set isLike column as 0 vice versa( like on/off)

Select the MyCookBook table which are the rows isLike as **1** is your "My personal Cookbook"

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Alright this does make allot of sense. 
However I am currently working with firebase, so the user has to input his/her e-mail and password and then they are able to use the application.
Should I still do it in a sqlite database or keep everything in firebase?

Comment: Does anyone have a reply on this question?